# The Transverality Theorem in Differentiable Topology by Guillemin and Pollack

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, transversality

In Chapter 2, Section 3 of the book, most of the theorems requires the codomain $Y$ to be a manifold without the boundary and the submanifold $Z$ to be boundaryless as well. But I don't see why the boundaryless conditions of $Y$ and $Z$ are important. For example, the Transversality Theorem stated as the following: 
Suppose that  $F: X\times S\rightarrow Y$ is a smooth map of manifolds, where only $X$ has boundary, and let $Z$ be any boundaryless submanifolds of $Y$. If both $F$ and $\partial F$ are transversal to $Z$, then for almost every $s\in S$, both $f_s$ and $\partial f_s$ are transversal to $Z$.
I tried to construct some counterexample where either $Z$ or $Y$ to be a manifold with boundary, but I have no idea about how to construct such counterexample. Could someone give me some concrete example where the theorem fails when $Z$ or $Y$ has boundary? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The issue is that if you run into the boundary of $Y$, it's impossible to come up with a parametrized family that is transverse to the boundary (because you will necessarily have to move "out" of $Y$). So the setting becomes vacuous.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I sort of understanding what you said here. <br/>

Comment: So the problem happened in the neighborhood of the boundary since the dimension of the boundary is 1-dimension smaller than the dimension of the interior, which contradicts with the transversal assumption. But is it possible that there is some "nice" map such that the preimage of boundary is contained in the boundary of X? Is such condition helpful to make the theorem work? Thank you.

Comment: Aha, so if you have $\partial f = f|_{\partial X}\colon\partial X\to\partial Y$ and you assume that $Z$ intersects $\partial Y$ transversely and both $F$ and $\partial F$ are transverse to $Z$ (as in the usual situation), you probably will be OK.